# Intercept method calls in a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code:

```
abstract class CommunicationChannel<Client> : IDisposable where Client :  class, IDisposable {
    protected Client client;

    public void Open() {
        try
        {
            client = CreateClient();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            client.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    public virtual void  Dispose() {
        client.Dispose();
    }

    private Client CreateClient()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<Client>();
    }
}

class Communicator : CommunicationChannel<Client>
{
    // here I have specific methods
    void Method1(args) {
        Open();

        try {
            client.Method1(args);
        }
        catch(Exception) {
            // Cleanup
        }
    }

    // this is getting too verbose already
    void Method2(args) {
        Open();

        try {
            client.Method2(args);
        }
        catch(Exception) {
            // Cleanup
        }
    }

} 

class Client: IDisposable {
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

I would want in the base class CommunicationChannel to be able to intercept somehow all the calls related to client and handle the exceptions before propagating them to the derived class CommunicationChannel. The generic parameter of the base class can contain different methods (in my example we only have Method 1)

I would ideally want a solution in which I don't have to call CommunicationChannel.CallMethod("Method1", args).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `client` private and force subclasses to access it in a `Func` or `Action`. You can then add you before/after logic:

```
abstract class CommunicationChannel<Client> : IDisposable where Client : class, IDisposable
{
    private Client client;

        protected TResult WithClient<TResult>(Func<Client, TResult> f)
        {
            this.Open();
            try
            {
                return f(client);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //cleanup
            }

            return default(TResult);
        }

    protected void WithClient(Action<Client> act)
    {
        WithClient<object>(c => { act(c); return null; })
    }
}
```

your subclasses can then do:

```
class Communicator : CommunicationChannel<Client> 
{
    bool Method1(args) 
    {
        return WithClient<bool>(c => { return c.Method1(args); });
    }
}
```

Comment: WithClient has to handle different return types also, e.g. types that c.MethodX return

Comment: Looks better :-). One stil needs when calling WithClient<specifyReturnType> and no deduction takes place for return value...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good case to use AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming).

What you could do is set up an aspect which OnEntry, executes the Open method and catches the exceptions with the OnException method.

Then all you have to do is decorate the methods you want to use that aspect on with an Attribute

Ill demonstrate what i mean using PostSharp:

```
public class CommunicationAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var communicationObject = args.Instance as CommunicationObject;
        communicationObject.Open();
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        _logger.log(string.Format("Exception {0} has occured on method {1}", args.Exception, args.Method.Name));
    }
}
```

Then, decorate your methods with this attribute:

```
class Communicator : CommunicationChannel<Client>
{
  [CommunicationAspect]
  void Method1(args) 
  {
     client.Method1(args);
  }

  [CommunicationAspect]
  void Method2(args)
  {
     client.Method2(args);
  }
}
```

[PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net) is a great framework that makes it really easy to get started, I suggest you look into it.

Comment: [CodeCop](http://getcodecop.com/)  is a library that builds on top of JSON to provide a fast unobtrusive way to write method interceptors for your .NET apps. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/codecop_team/codecop/wiki/Home)  is a wiki.

You can try this :)